# UIWebView(DataDetectorsCore) Crash only in Simulator

Tags: iphone, crash, webview

I found a crash only in iphone simulator while loading the webpage but not in iphone,and i am not able to find the reason of the crash in my app.

Here i am attached the crash log.

Can any one please suggesting the fix regarding these crash.

```
Process:         Matador [28671]
Path:            /Users/chethan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/F36CD2A2-7AAA-4817-91BD-30AAAD46A050/Matador.app/Matador
Identifier:      Matador
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [83]

Interval Since Last Report:          2801293 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           98
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  0 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   15

Date/Time:       2010-04-06 18:19:26.768 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L30)
Report Version:  6
Anonymous UUID:  9279BCFF-6687-4205-9FAA-7503103AB25F

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000c1587497
Crashed Thread:  5

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 3.1 (139.1), iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954a0286 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954a7a7c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x30244d62 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1842
3   CoreFoundation                 0x30244628 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 88
4   GraphicsServices               0x32044c31 GSEventRunModal + 217
5   GraphicsServices               0x32044cf6 GSEventRun + 115
6   UIKit                          0x309021ee UIApplicationMain + 1157
7   Matador                        0x0000281c main + 102 (main.m:13)
8   Matador                        0x0000278a start + 54

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954a64a4 szone_free + 138
1   CoreFoundation                 0x302044a1 _CFRelease + 369
2   UIKit                          0x30b3afd2 -[UITextTapRecognizer dealloc] + 78
3   CoreFoundation                 0x302042e8 CFRelease + 136
4   CoreFoundation                 0x302275f2 __CFArrayReleaseValues + 434
5   CoreFoundation                 0x302571ae CFArrayRemoveAllValues + 126
6   UIKit                          0x3091c506 -[UIView(UIViewGestures) removeAllGestureRecognizers] + 262
7   UIKit                          0x30b5ce3e -[UIWebSelectionAssistant setGestureRecognizers] + 39
8   UIKit                          0x30a542ca -[UIWebDocumentView loadRequest:] + 250
9   CoreFoundation                 0x3024a10d __invoking___ + 29
10  CoreFoundation                 0x30249ff8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 136
11  WebCore                        0x3588eee3 __ZL15HandleAPISourcePv + 147
12  CoreFoundation                 0x302452c1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 3217
13  CoreFoundation                 0x30244628 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 88
14  WebCore                        0x3588ea13 __ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 467
15  libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1155 _pthread_start + 321
16  libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1012 thread_start + 34

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954a0286 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954a7a7c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x30244d62 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1842
3   CoreFoundation                 0x30244628 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 88
4   Foundation                     0x3056002e +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 318
5   Foundation                     0x3050a79d -[NSThread main] + 45
6   Foundation                     0x3050a338 __NSThread__main__ + 280
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1155 _pthread_start + 321
8   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1012 thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954ef6fa select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1155 _pthread_start + 321
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1012 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954a746e __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1dcd pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 73
2   WebCore                        0x35da0ff0 WebCore::LocalStorageThread::localStorageThread() + 160
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1155 _pthread_start + 321
4   libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1012 thread_start + 34

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x90560688 objc_msgSend + 24
1   CoreFoundation                 0x302887c8 __CFSTUnitWordSentenceLineSetString + 200
2   DataDetectorsCore              0x351eb7be _FillNextTokenInCache + 142
3   DataDetectorsCore              0x351ebc15 DDTokenCacheGetTokensAtPosition + 141
4   DataDetectorsCore              0x351ebcfc DDTokenCacheGetTokenOrSubtokenAfterPosition + 53
5   DataDetectorsCore              0x351e3f5f DDScannerScanQuery + 133
6   DataDetectorsUI                0x36f915c1 -[DDOperation main] + 436
7   Foundation                     0x30577345 -[NSOperation start] + 469
8   Foundation                     0x3050a79d -[NSThread main] + 45
9   Foundation                     0x3050a338 __NSThread__main__ + 280
10  libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1155 _pthread_start + 321
11  libSystem.B.dylib              0x954d1012 thread_start + 34

Thread 5 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x010babd0  ebx: 0x3020b834  ecx: 0x905e2f98  edx: 0xc1587477
  edi: 0x00000002  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xb0217718  esp: 0xb02176a8
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x90560688   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0xc1587497

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x5efff +Matador ??? (???) <17a74d7981867f7ee76fe9b44034e203> /Users/chethan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/F36CD2A2-7AAA-4817-91BD-30AAAD46A050/Matador.app/Matador
   0xf6000 -    0xf9fff +ArtworkCache ??? (???) <dc0fe8f121b577c93eb9eb4a8d2e0a71> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
  0x100000 -   0x308ffc  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.359.16 (???) <25dd6285e4c73a2a57d8e39aeaed66ca> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
  0x356000 -   0x3e9fe7 +CFNetwork ??? (???) <87c9708e7163be274d075cc2e4a56cf0> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
  0x456000 -   0x4f3fef +QuartzCore ??? (???) <495e891d3eef105c25ed695bcffd48df> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
  0x532000 -   0x6a7ff7 +libicucore.A.dylib ??? (???) <4782454ee651edadb2ef302d2713512e> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
  0x6f1000 -   0x7f0ff3 +libxml2.2.dylib ??? (???) <50e3af719240d8bd782c7fb63c3e9f95> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  0x80e000 -   0x8c3ffb +libsqlite3.dylib ??? (???) <08a8dce024d0dc81b4ad5b699c580fe9> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  0x8d2000 -   0x95dfff  com.apple.framework.IOKit 1.5.1 (???) <a17f9f5ea7e8016a467e67349f4d3d03> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
  0x983000 -   0xaa9fe3 +JavaScriptCore ??? (???) <051637e757e637ee1f9adeb58dac7128> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
  0xaf9000 -   0xbb2fef +ImageIO ??? (???) <6557cfafe69f3c38e62659433a404fff> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
  0xbd8000 -   0xc01feb +AppSupport ??? (???) <0c4f359bf157f47da547c684ec6ce18f> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
  0xc1c000 -   0xc29fee +MobileCoreServices ??? (???) <2a58785af37061793fb085146efd603f> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
  0xc34000 -   0xc9eff7 +CoreAudio ??? (???) <8c6c1fa2a106be7ddf4a6d40d7471b00> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
  0xcdf000 -   0xceafff +IAP ??? (???) <5799b1cb019ea05ab7e88e8a37e983f6> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
  0xcf7000 -   0xcfbfff +ITSync ??? (???) <e4bf7193014729765e7ff862fd4a7bb4> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
  0xd0e000 -   0xd19ff7 +CoreVideo ??? (???) <a07c312d6edc3e20e26d50c3fc988f3a> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
  0xd22000 -   0xd38fff +OpenGLES ??? (???) <2e723544dfbaf0efc9935bbb0a0babdf> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
  0xd3d000 -   0xd8ffef +GMM ??? (???) <eeecc86cc2298b012c869699f4527a73> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
  0xddf000 -   0xedcfff +MediaToolbox ??? (???) <ba0c0af4bb0051f67e077e2ba3b47272> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
 0x143d000 -  0x1463fff +libRIP.A.dylib ??? (???) <40de2be56e0f06be12259aa4e92c62e9> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
 0x146a000 -  0x14acfff +libCGFreetype.A.dylib ??? (???) <70ef15c06c83f196a69bedbc752b2d13> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
 0x1512000 -  0x1517fff +libgermantok.dylib ??? (???) <bd46334394a3de0380d36720c4fff600> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x301fd000 - 0x302fffe7 +CoreFoundation ??? (???) <22d1c094e36af3e77391d3373dc3733a> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30501000 - 0x30682fff +Foundation ??? (???) <784caddc2598cba98d5aebac1735e261> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x308ed000 - 0x31a0afe0 +UIKit ??? (???) <ac0bc64814331a08d9f7af36ba65b12c> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31ea9000 - 0x31fd2fff +AudioToolbox ??? (???) <3171eca73e40432385b45cbc20d8dcd9> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32041000 - 0x32048ff7 +GraphicsServices ??? (???) <72dae2caff7e3f59b25a31ee4bdda802> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32056000 - 0x3207dfeb +CoreLocation ??? (???) <1f6c26e3c8192fea21b969b6084d8632> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3209b000 - 0x320eeff4 +Security ??? (???) <71ba152cad65f1eb98f2c183004db2c9> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32369000 - 0x3239bfff +SystemConfiguration ??? (???) <a1cda20380d841d14cda9190e4f9c875> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x323c3000 - 0x3243bfe2 +MusicLibrary ??? (???) <8bb105498ba4c7ef2d4614985f47e998> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x325b2000 - 0x325cdfff +AddressBook ??? (???) <445a75cc201c56faf36df61e36b050f1> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x332c9000 - 0x3334dfff +WebKit ??? (???) <5b79d41ed991585c9d9bcd015074fc39> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x333d1000 - 0x333f6fff +Celestial ??? (???) <4175215094b947a618f2620b5f67ab47> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33703000 - 0x3376cff2 +MediaPlayer ??? (???) <2df5651deb3ed0bd4ce737fc07abc303> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x3415c000 - 0x34167ffc +SpringBoardServices ??? (???) <9318a36e89ce24da26bd7ede99e64e32> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34716000 - 0x3474afe3 +CoreMedia ??? (???) <6206ce19107a4571f6a488c28feee743> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34775000 - 0x34adefeb +VideoToolbox ??? (???) <bf1ada6691eb7d6ae7f10be33984de44> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x351e0000 - 0x351effff +DataDetectorsCore ??? (???) <d8a9a76e818b71981b0b14456e97dd46> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x3553d000 - 0x35579fff +CoreText ??? (???) <5e168a089d1338d658da3d0d8024fd9f> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x356ab000 - 0x356b0fff +WebUI ??? (???) <3e57ebb299630d44da4699202c236907> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x357b2000 - 0x357e6ff2 +TextInput ??? (???) <7a9c69d340c02614760791780fc98b93> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3580a000 - 0x35f35fef +WebCore ??? (???) <4d12d9bdfd11860510a5de961c2ac732> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36595000 - 0x365bafeb +MobileQuickLook ??? (???) <46ebca3fcfe1da8cf3568fba11771c91> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x36645000 - 0x3664bfff +ProtocolBuffer ??? (???) <84f4a119eff0fb996663a7573409aaf9> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36f8c000 - 0x36f95fff +DataDetectorsUI ??? (???) <48d993e04d6805c8d6ff9691caf51a24> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x37119000 - 0x37119ffc +liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <794cc40edc285f2ed19dc48dae1b2f22> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe2db43  dyld 97.1 (???) <458eed38a009e5658a79579e7bc26603> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x9002efe7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <4f3e58cb81da07a1662c1f647ce30225> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x90039000 - 0x900ebffb  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <8ac6abef4b3bb125c8bf84634421bcee> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
0x9054b000 - 0x9062bfff  libobjc.A.dylib ??? (???) <3ca288b625a47bbcfe378158e4dc328f> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x9062c000 - 0x906f3ff2  com.apple.vImage 3.0 (3.0) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x91a9e000 - 0x91a9effd  com.apple.vecLib 3.4.2 (vecLib 3.4.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x91ac2000 - 0x91ae6feb  libssl.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <1ffdb9ff23c05f6205233e3f2956f82e> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
0x91cd3000 - 0x91cdaffe  libbsm.dylib ??? (???) <d25c63378a5029648ffd4b4669be31bf> /usr/lib/libbsm.dylib
0x9200d000 - 0x9200dffd  com.apple.Accelerate 1.4.2 (Accelerate 1.4.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x92cf2000 - 0x93102fef  libBLAS.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x93c17000 - 0x93fd5fea  libLAPACK.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x9549f000 - 0x95606ff3  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <ae47ca9b1686b065f8ac4d2de09cc432> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x957b0000 - 0x9582dfef  libvMisc.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x95fa7000 - 0x95fb5ffd  libz.1.dylib ??? (???) <5ddd8539ae2ebfd8e7cc1c57525385c7> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x95fb6000 - 0x95fbafff  libmathCommon.A.dylib ??? (???) /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x96018000 - 0x96045feb  libvDSP.dylib ??? (???) <f39d424bd56a0e75d5c7a2280a25cd76> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x9722e000 - 0x9728bffb  libstdc++.6.dylib ??? (???) <04b812dcec670daa8b7d2852ab14be60> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x974c8000 - 0x974cffe9  libgcc_s.1.dylib ??? (???) <f53c808e87d1184c0f9df63aef53ce0b> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0xfffe8000 - 0xfffebfff  libobjc.A.dylib ??? (???) /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1780  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it 100% reproducible? Is it crashing in iPhone Simulator > 3.1? May be this is an iPhone SDK issue...

Similar crash discussed here... http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg43716.html

Comment: remove unnecessary lines... add only related info in crash report.